# Birational Calabi-Yau varieties with non-isomorphic cohomological invariants

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, mirror-symmetry

We know from the work of Kontsevich, for example, that birational Calabi-Yau complex varieties have the same Hodge numbers. I want to understand to what extent the equivalence of cohomological invariants fails for two such varieties. Precisely, I am looking for examples of birational Calabi-Yau varieties over any field that have some non-isomorphic cohomological invariants (Chow groups, Hodge structures, K-groups, cohomology groups, etc.)

Comment: I believe that the result you attribute to Kontsevich was proved earlier by Chi-Lung Wang following ideas of Batyrev.  Anyway, the product (i.e., the ring structure) on cohomology is not always invariant under K-equivalence.   The Crepant Transformation Conjecture of Ruan predicts how the ring structure behaves, after extending from cohomology to quantum cohomology and then allowing an analytic continuation.

Comment: Typo correction: "Chi-Lung Wang" --> "Chin-Lung Wang".  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at arXiv:math/0703315.
It gives an explicit pair of birational Calabi-Yau threefolds which are cohomologically non-isomorphic.